# How to Start Activity from Bottom Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application which contains bottom navigation drawer, Till now every thing is working fine but when i am adding click listener, the action which i am performing is not working.

bottombar_tabs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <tab
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/tab_favorites"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_map_black_24dp"
        android:title="Land" />

    <tab
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/tab_nearby"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_directions"
        android:title="Vehicle" />

    <tab
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/tab_friends"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_inbox_black_24dp"
        android:title="Equipment" />

</tabs>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fishPriceList"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:background="#003300"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_filter_list" />


    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:bb_tabXmlResource="@layout/bottombar_tabs" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

In java class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
         bottomBar.setOnTabReselectListener(new OnTabReselectListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabReSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {

       if (tabId == R.id.tab_nearby){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem actually you are facing?

Comment: I am not getting toast, when i am clciking on perticular library

Comment: Trying to use android native viewpager tabs dear it gives more customization

Comment: https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: I referred to this library, but click listener is not working. i want to show toast. am i doing something wrong??

Comment: Check this Example : http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/                                                      http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation-part-2/

Comment: @KritiJain i have posted code try like  it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this

```
 bottomBar.setOnTabselectListener(new OnTabselectListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hello How are you?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please Tell me what is TabMessage?

Comment: its custom class to display message

Comment: you just check using static string

Comment: please check i have updated my code, i am still not getting toast :(

Comment: @KritiJain try selectlistener and put debug point on that and start app debug

Comment: @KritiJain wait? what are you going to do. you have taken recycler view inside main activity layout. you want to display list on tab item then you have to create fragment for it. and in main activity you have to use frame layout.

Comment: I disagree with the accepted answer, I debugged the code and found the problem:

tabId always arrives with a corrupt value equal to 1.

Check my answer below to see the solution

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the accepted answer, I debugged the code and found the problem:

tabId always arrives with a corrupt value equal to 1.

Apparently the issue has already been [identified](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar/issues/435)

[image]

SOLUTION:

1 - **Delete** your bottombar_tabs.xml

2 - Create a folder folder for XML files in resources, **outside of layouts folder**
[image]

3 - create a new bottombar_tabs.xml **WITHOUT** the `android:` namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs>
    <tab
        layout_height="50dp"
       id="@+id/tab_favorites"
       icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        title="Land" />

    <tab
        layout_height="50dp"
        id="@+id/tab_nearby"
        icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        title="Vehicle" />

    <tab
        layout_height="50dp"
        id="@+id/tab_friends"
        icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        title="Equipment" />
</tabs>
```

4 - In your activity_main.xml layout use the new XML

```
<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/tabs_final" />
```

Voila, it's done =)

Comment: @Kriti Jain have you been able to solve your problem? I believe this answer should be marked as the correct one, let me know if this helped =)